# Дохристианское название креста

Tags: история, славянские-языки

Русские слова *крест* и *крыж* имеют общий иноязычный корень: оба восходят к греческому *Χριστός*, то есть "Христос". А было ли какое-то исконное название у этой священной для многих культур фигуры (пересечённых линий)?

Answer (score 2):

Мне нравится такая версия.

Было древнее славянское слово "Рис", которое означает отрезок прямой линии, начерченный на осматриваемом предмете. Слово "Крес" ("к рису", "е" - тут преобразованное "и"), означало ребро, край, границу какого-либо предмета, а "Крест" - соединение двух предметов их краями в форме буквы "Х" или знака "+". Отсюда и до сих пор сохранившееся слово "окрест", "окрестность", что значит: около "креста", т.е. область, окружающая точку пересечения "рисов". Кстати, и "крестьянин" от "христианин" мне тоже не нравится. А почему не так: крестьянин - тот,кто живёт в окрестностях города, не в городе.

Глагол "скрестить" поэтому означал соединять два предмета в виде "Х", а "крестить" — значит ударять их друг о друга краями, высекая огненные искры, что использовалось для разжигания огня — отсюда и слово "кресало" — камень, ударением о который другим твердым предметом легко высекались искры. Поэтому первоначальное , дохристианское слово "Крещение" означало зажигание огня посредством высекания искр, "загорение"; а "Воскресение" - возгорание огня, произведенное с помощью "загорания", т.е. высекания искр, "крещения", т.е. значит "Возгорение", "Воспламенение". А уже христианство приспособило емкость древнего славянского языка и его  смысловую символику.

От слова крес( крѣсъ — черта, точка, предел (возможно от *k(')er- со значением царапать, скрести)в древнерусском языке были производные: крѣсити — оживлять, возрождать, воскрешать (в слове воскрешать, точно нельзя подразумевать заимствование, данное слово - исконнославянское); креска - черты, линия; кресляти — писать знаками; крѣсный — критический ; кресокъ — перекресток (нет "т", значит заимствование, по всей вероятности, исключается).

Сопоставляя слово «крест» со словами из других языков, А.Афанасьев в своей книге «Поэтические воззрения славян на природу» (М., 1994, т. 3, стр. 712) пишет: «Словенцы называют Иванов день и самый поворот солнца – kres (кроат. kresz = огонь), а месяц июнь – kresnik; серб, кресови – dies solstitiales («три дана npnje и три nocneje Илища дне»), Kpnjec – огонь, разводимый накануне Иванова, Витова, Петрова и Юрьева дней, с которыми народная мысль связывает старинные воспоминания о боге-громовнике, возжигателе небесного пламени» И еще (А. Афанасьев. Т. 1, стр. 255):
«Кръсить, кресать, польск. krzesac, словен. kresati – высекать огонь
из кремня и обтачивать камень (жернов), кресало = огниво».
Таким образом, слово «крест» имеет языческое происхождение и связано с понятием «огонь» и «солнцестояние» .

В свою очередь, древнерусское слово «крест» означает «оживание», отсюда – воскреснуть, то есть ожить: «ибо воскресать (въскръшати, крьснжти, кръсити) происходит от кръсъ – пламя, огонь. В одном рукописном прологе слова кръсъ и кръсины употреблены именно въ значении небесного света, возженного при по-
вороте солнца на лето: «въ дьни слъньчнаго кръса, ъгда ся наплъныдимъ годинамъ слъньце възвратить кръсины, да ношть мьняеть (уменьшается), а дьни да прибываеть». Вновь народившееся или воскресшее светило постепенно крепнет въ своих силах; божественный младенец растет и мужает и при начале весны является прекрасным и могучим юношей» (А. Афанасьев. Т. 1, стр. 188).

Слова "Христос" и "крест", хотя и кажутся близкими и родственными словами, но на самом деле совершенно разные и далекие друг от друга слова."Христос" - это слово греческого происхождения является полным синонимом еврейского слова "Мессия", а русское значение этих слов — "Помазанный". "Помазанный" — это человек, над которым совершили помазание елеем (оливковым маслом) при назначении на определенную миссию или задачу ("миссия" с ударением на первом слоге и "Мессия" с ударением на втором слоне — это разные слова, с разными значениями, хотя происхождение у них общее). Обычно помазывали на царство или на иное лидерство, в том числе и духовное. Помазание происходило путем возливания оливкового масла на голову человека, назначаемого на царство или иной высокий пост. Иисус стал называться Христом или Мессией в момент Его помазания Духом Святым на исполнение роли Спасителя человечества при Его крещении у Иоанна Крестителя.
"Крест" — это любое пересечение двух прямых, чаще под прямым углом, оно не имеет никакого родства со словом "Христос". Единственная взаимосвязь этих двух слов заключается в том, что крест стал популярным только потому, что Христос был распят на кресте, здесь чистая случайность в том, что слова "крест" и "Христос" так близки по звучанию. В данном случае, крест — это то орудие казни, которое было применено ко Христу. Впоследствии крест стал одним из символом христианства, но опять таки, не по причине сходства слов, а по причине того, какую роль крест играл в жизни Христа и в истории христианской церкви.

Comment: Вот ещё почитайте, интересно, и про "крыж" есть: http://vk.com/topic-38761535_27916358

Comment: В древнерусском языке КРЕСТЬЯНИН назывался словом <<смерд>> . Во всех других славянских языках это понятие отображается совсем другими корнями . Поэтому , слово КРЕСТЬЯНИН вряд ли может быть древнеславянским и связанным с "точкой соединения рисов" . Для КРЕСТЬЯНИНА более реальна ивритная этимология : חרוֹש  хараш , в по-буквенном прочтении (справа-налево) хет-реш-вав-шин = Х(гортанное)-Р-А(О)-С(Ш) , - в переводе означает <<ПАХАТЬ>> . Добавление суффиксного окончания Т-Н здесь аналогично латинскому -tian или английскому -tion (revolution , conversation , presentation и др.) .

Comment: Боже, ну каким образом ивритское слово могло оказаться в славянском? Тем более, что Вы сами пишете, что в родственных языках понятие совсем другими словами отображается.

Comment: *Было древнее славянское слово "Рис", которое означает отрезок прямой линии, начерченный на осматриваемом предмете. Слово "Крес" ("к рису", "е" - тут преобразованное "и"), означало ребро, край, границу какого-либо предмета, а "Крест" - соединение двух предметов их краями в форме буквы "Х" или знака "+"* - Людмила, что-то тут Фоменкой со товарищи сильно пахнет. Совершенно искуственная трактовка морфологии "креста" и полное игнорирование соображений и.-е. родственности с "крыжем", которую все в той или иной степени признают.

Comment: Я вообще не уверен, что в те времена, когда предлоги становильсь приставками, предлог "К" существовал в подобном виде. Было, какжется что-то типа "кон", которое потом сократилось до "КЪ".

Comment: Для behemothus`а . Ивритных слов в русском языке гораздо больше , чем вы в состоянии себе представить . И обратите внимание , что наряду с формой <<крестьяне>>  в письменных источниках промелькнула и форма <<хрестьяне>> , через Х . И не забывайте , что иврит вместе с греческим и латинским входил в тройку священных языков . Была и группировка грамотеев , называвшихся трёхъязычниками , с которыми вёл дискуссию просветитель Кирилл . И , если  слово из православной  Москвы не попало к православным болгарам , сербам и украинцам ,  это объяснимо фронтом турецкого нашествия .и польской экспансией .

Answer (score 1):

> Русские слова крест и крыж имеют общий иноязычный корень: оба восходят к греческому Χριστός, то есть "Христос"

Это не так. "Крест" может быть связан с Христом, но не образован из него.
Т.е. крест и Христос восходят к одной и той же и.-е.  основе, но появились в языке независимо друг от друга, и, таким образом, нет никаких причин отказывать "кресту" (слову) в существовании задолго до появления христианства и тем более - знакомства с ним славян.

Здесь нет достоверных источников, Лукашевича, я изъял, ибо жемчужное зерно в его навозе не каждому дано выкопать, но в принципе в одном он прав, Фасмера нельзя понимать так прямолинейно, что слово "крест" заимствовано через Христос.

Вот на тему креста небольшая дискуссия, но по узкому вопросу мало что добавляет к изложенному.
http://lingvoforum.net/index.php/topic,33683.0.html

"Крыж" же там рядом не лежал. Понятно, что "крыж" родственен кресту, но с Христом может быть связан только очень далекой историей.

http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-6210.htm

Скорее всего крыж (лат сruх, «крест») - от индоевропейского корня со значением «искривлённый».

Comment: Каким образом слово "крест" может происходить от той же основы, что и слово "Христос", если у них совершенно разные значения? Христос — это помазанник, от греческого глагола  χρίω ("мазать", "натирать").

Comment: Обыкновенным. "Крест" восходит к основам, не имеющим подобного значения ("крест"). Почитайте дискуссию на лингвофоруме, раз Вы этих вещей не понимаете.

Comment: Я хочу видеть ссылки на авторитетные источники, а не прения неизвестных людей с неизвестной компетенцией. 

Каким образом слово "крест" могло возникнуть из и.-е. основы, имеющей иное значение, само по себе? Когда и как произошёл семантический сдвиг, чем он был обусловлен? Происхождение от слова "Христос" этот сдвиг объясняет вполне убедительно. Кстати, какие Ваши контаргументы против господствующей версии?

Comment: Ну хотите, кто ж Вам запрещает-то? Найдет авторитетный - расскажете, где и как.

Comment: Кстати Я хочу тоже видеть вопросы от компетентных людей, а не от тех, которые задают вопросы "как могло возникнуть?" Объясните для начала, почему не могло.

Comment: Это форум не компетентных вопросов, а компетентных ответов. Никаких доводов в том обсуждении в пользу того, что слово "крест" восходит к и.-е. корню, который потом в греческом языке дал слово "мазать, натирать", приведено не было.

Comment: А вы точно компетентны решать, что здесь компетентно?  Так не вопрос.Найдите мне компетентное мнение, что вопросы типа "Каким образом" имеют решение в принципе.

Comment: *Никаких доводов в том обсуждении в пользу того, что слово "крест" восходит к и.-е. корню, который потом в греческом языке дал слово "мазать, натирать", приведено не было.* - а вот это уже другой вопрос. Вы интересовались "каким образом", а не доводами. Так что, если сформулируете вопрос корректно, получите и компетентный ответ, если он в принципе есть.

Comment: Я в состоянии посмотреть, на что опираются участники обсуждения, и увидеть, что всё сводится к их толкованию и домыслам, а не научным концепциям, поддержанным научным сообществом. На вопрос "каким образом" ни Вы, ни участники той дискуссии ответа не дали, потому что без доводов концепцию ответом считать неприемлемо. С таким же успехом можно сослаться на Божий промысел.

Comment: Ну смотрите на здоровье, я-то при чем? Мое мнение, надеюсь, до Вас дошло. А кричать "сделайте мне красиво!" - это не ко мне. Прошу извинить, отвечать на подобное я не буду, даже если Вы на Божий промысел сошлетесь. Вопрос "каким образом" не относится к числу корректных. Если Вы знаете ответ - валяйте. А если его не знает никто - нечего  тут права качать.

Comment: Подведём итог. Ваше утверждение ("Крест" может быть связан с Христом, но не образован из него), которое противоречит Фасмеру, ничем не подтверждено.

Comment: Вы это себя во множественном числе называете? Мой итог другой. Вы не знаете, к чему прицепиться. Мое *"Крест" может быть связан с Христом, но не образован из него* - не нуждается в подтверждении, ибо противоречит не Фасмеру, а Вашему его, Фасмера, извращенного пониманию. И не решайте больше за Фасмера.э

Comment: Аргументируйте на основе Фасмера своё утверждение.

Comment: Зачем? Аргументируйте Вы свое. Я выразился достаточно прозрачно. Мое утверждение не противоречит Фасмеру.

Comment: А вообще - "все в сад!" В смысле - в чат.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35896/discussion-between-behemothus-and-).

Comment: Вы не привели ни одного контраргумента. Вывод очевиден.

Answer (score 0):

Исконное значение слова "воскреснуть" это не заново ожить, а это кресту возобновиться и пойти на очередной цикл.

Кресты были распространены в наскальной живописи и были центральными символами религий в дохристианские и доисторические времена. Они не зависели ни от чего, считались проявлением высшей силы и символизировали верховный закон природы, когда других законов не знали. Сами слова Христос и христианство (крестьянство) произошли от слова крест.

Считалось, что Солнце управляет днем, а Луна ночью, поэтому дни полнолуний, когда полная луна восходит строго на закате солнца считались священными. В этот день солнце и луна встречаются только на закате.

Раньше не было ни календарей ни часов. Время дня и года узнавали только по небу, луне и солнцу.

Лунный крест это 4 фазы луны: новолуние, полулуние, поднолуние, полулуние. Люди с далеких мест могли смело сходиться в новолуние на ярмарку, не боясь, что ошибутся днем. В те времена от этого порой зависела жизнь.
Фазы луны давали недели. По Библии 6 дней люди работали, седьмой день попадал на лунный крест.

Новорожденный месяц теряется в лучах солнца и новолуние могло определяться с ошибками от 1-2 дней в южных широтах до нескольких дней на Севере. Крест, как бы прерывался в неопределенности до времени появления нового месяца, дающего отчет в продолжении "вращения" креста в его бесконечном цикле. Тому, кто первый замечал новый месяц полагалась награда. Новолуние это воскресение лунного креста, лунного месяца.
Из-за надежности определения фаз луны и меньшей выраженности сезонов года (солнечный крест) южане использовали в основном лунный календарь (мусульмане), а для северян использование лунного календаря становилось совсем невозможным и они использовали в основном солнечный крест (солнцепоклонники).

Когда небо закрыла мгла во время Исхода из Египта - Пасхи, что значит "прохождение",  библейские евреи перешли с астрономического лунного календаря, на счетные субботы, отсюда пошел мусульманский лунный календарь. Лунный крест не синхронизирован с солнечным, каждые три года древние вставляли дополнительный лунный месяц в год, чтобы синхронизировать их.

Цивилизация объединила солнечный и луный кресты для расчета календарной Пасхи. Самая древняя астрономическая Пасха это первое полнолуние после весеннего равноденствия. Начало иудейской Пасхи в первую счетную субботу после астрономической. Христианская в первое воскреснье после недели иудейской.

Рождение нового года раньше отмечали в разные эпохи во все точки солнечного креста, образованного 4 неизменными точками, двумя равноденствиями и двумя солнцестояниями. Сегодня это 20 марта, 21 июня, 22 сентября, 21 декабря. Солнечный крест дает времена года. 21 декабря древние боялись, что солнце продолжит опускаться и мир погибнет, поэтому этот день сегодня называют Рождество, с этого дня солнце вновь все выше и выше в полдень, мир возрождается. В дни равноденствий Солнце восходит строго на географическом Востоке, а заходит на географическом Западе. Это золотой день для картографов, когда можно объединить в одну большую карту планы местностей.

Попытки примитивно рассуждать о сложном привели к вопросу: откуда Бог знает о чаяниях людей, если он не жил человеческой жизнью. По христианству, Бог рождается от женщины и Духа святого и живет жизнью обычного человека до распятия. На третий день после смерти он живой является своим апостолам. Это называют воскрешением или воскресением Христовым.

Однако, словообразование нам говорит, что "воскресение" это не оживание умершего, а возобновление креста, именно поэтому воскресение приурочено к одной из точек солнечного креста. Зимой Рождество (солнца), весной Воскресение (как бы воскресение природы), летом праздновали сбор урожая,  а осенью приплод скота. Все эти великие религиозные праздники изначально были приурочены к солнечному кресту.

Если изучить словообразование слова "воскресение" , то согласно «Русской грамматике» под ред. Н.Ю. Шведовой, данная приставка имеет четыре значения:

1. подняться вверх (воспарить);
2. вновь совершить действие (воссоединить);
3. начать действие (вознегодовать);
4. довести действие до результата (возмужать).

В 1-ом и 4-ом случаях так же можно интерпретировать значения, как повтор чего-то, так как то, что воспарило, когда-то могло парить или потенциально могло парить, тот, кто возмужал, повторял то, что происходило с его предками.

В свете обьяснения для слова "вос + крест + нуть" более подходит значение возобновление креста в моменты новолуния и Рождества, когда по верованиям древних вращения "небесных шестеренок" крестов луны или солнца могли остановиться и мир мог погибнуть.

### Мои видеообъяснения:
Этот текст https://youtu.be/Y9uINyc7ImA ,
https://youtu.be/IeGwW2o5tSQ
https://youtu.be/7kzDdLJor4A
https://youtu.be/p7Pa3us64CI
https://youtu.be/Q_EqU0s56e8

дополнительно

Приставки воз/вос противопоставояются низ/нис, но это неверно.

Приставки воз/вос имеют самостоятельное значение возобновления/повторного действия. Например, возьмем из Wiktionary:

образует глаголы со значением направления действия вверх ◆ возноситься, воспарить, возрастать , восстать, восходить.

Это так же можно представить, что что-то уже нисходило,

помещения в устойчивое положение ◆ возлечь, воссесть.

Однако, всегда это повтор такого же предыдущего действия.

созидания, объединения ◆ возродить, возрождать, воссоединить, восстановить

Это подразумевает, что что-то уже сузествовало, было цельным и исправным. Например, "воссоединение Крыма с Россией", подразумевается именно возобновление предыдущего действия или состояния.

собственно совершения действия ◆ возвещать, возблагодарить, восхвалить, восхвалять

https://m.facebook.com/story.php?story_fbid=4022753071146415&id=100002352868675

Answer (score -1):

@behemothus прав .

> "Крест" может быть связан с Христом, но не образован из него. ... нет никаких причин отказывать "кресту" (слову) в существовании задолго до появления христианства и тем более - знакомства с ним славян.

Помимо латинского  **сruх** , означающего *Т-образное орудие казни* , я обнаружил в словаре ещё и латинское  **cruciatus**, a, um; **cruciformis**, e = **крестообразный** . /// Что же касается имени <<**ХРИСТОС**>> , то здесь не греческий , а иврит , который греко-византийские редакторы отождествили с греческим *Χριστός = помазанник* - как перевод еврейского <<*машиах*>> . На иврите **הרעשת**  *по-буквенно* /справа-налево/ *хей-реш-айн-шин-тав* = **Х**-**Р**-**И**(**А**)-**С**(**Ш**)-**Т**  означает <<**ПОДНИМАНИЕ ШУМА**>> , а также  <<**ШУМЕТЬ** , **СОТРЯЧАТЬ** , **ПРОИЗВОДИТЬ СЕНСАЦИЮ**>> ( и , более современное , <<БОМБАРДИРОВКА , КАННОНАДА>>) . *Примечание* : *ивритная ע айн не имеет конкретного звука и часто озвучивается , как* **И** и **А** ; *а ה хей это заглатываемая* **Х** , *которая может не произноситься* ; *ש шин озвучивается , как*  **С** и **Ш** . Ну , сам носитель имени-прозвища , в сущности , таковым и являлся , как это переводится с иврита . /// Есть также и ивритная форма **הרעש** , - без последней **ת** *тав* , - = **ХРИШ** / **ХРИС** с тем же самым смыслом , что и **הרעשת** , и поляки со своим **крыжем** отталкивались от неё , смешивая при этом (переходом **Х** в **К** и **Ш** в польско-адаптированную **Ж**) имя **Христос** с тем сооружением , на котором он был распят . /// Обратим внимание , что , помимо самого Спасителя , был и святой по имени **ХРИСТ** , - албанский серб , живший в Стамбуле и обезглавленный турками-магометанами в 1748-м году . И на Балканах (у южных славян) существует вариант имени этого православного святого , который выглядит , как **РИСТ** (без первой **Х**) , - не случайно , выше я отметил что ивритная ה хей может не произноситься .  [image: ИРИС-словарь Х-Р-С-Т]   [image: ИРИС-словарь Х-Р-И-Ш]

Comment: Я рад, что я в чем-то прав, но читать Вас - сущее мучение, наглядная агитация вызывает у меня ощущение беспомощного лектора, действующего через внушение, а не через разум.  А на кой Вы сюда еще и Иврит приплели, если значение корневого морфа "Христос" идет из греческого, а не из иврита, где может означать вообще все что угодно?

Comment: Прежде чем минусовать , постарайтесь хоть как-то проследить ход мысли того , с кем Вы самоцельно ведёте конфронтацию . Специально для Вас поясняю : был религиозный реформатор , который от иудеев получил прозвище Христ (перевод с иврита в моем ответе) ; греки-византийцы редактируя христианские тексты истолковали это прозвище через греческий язык , превратив в Христ-оса=помазанника . Любой историк-религиовед подтвердит Вам  , что тексты новозаветного канона содержат следы правок и вставок  . Вообще , Вы в отношении меня ведёте дискуссию непринципиально , возражаете даже там , где ...

Comment: возражаете даже там , где не можете найти контр-аргументов , - это наглядно видно в вашем комменте моего ответа по Саше-Шуре .

Comment: Вот представьте, ни разу не возражаю. Просто не читал из-за проблем с оформлением. О чем честно и сказал. Одно то, что вы сюда притащили пол иврит словаря, уже вызывает отторжение. Ну не читают тут на иврите - и проверить достоверность сведений вами сообщаемых не могут.

Comment: Кстати, я Вам не минусовал. )))

Comment: Хорошо . Насчёт минусовки беру свои слова обратно (я Вам верю) . А , что касается скриншотов , то я для того их и помещаю , чтобы было понятно и доказательно тем , кто стремится разобраться и не ленится вникать в вопрос до конца . Лингвистика тем и сложна , что не имеет однозначности в доводах и требует сопоставлений и интуитивного мышления в сочетании с хоть каким-то историческим кругозором .

Comment: Так как его звали евреи? Мессией или Христом?