# Крест и Христос

Tags: этимология, славянские-языки

Этимологические словари русского языка, например Фасмера, Черных, Цыганенко и Крылова, сообщают, что слово *крест* восходит к слову *Христос*. Цитата из Фасмера:

> Первонач. *krьstъ означало "Христос" и произошло из д.-в.-н. krist, christ.
>   Более далекое в фонетическом отношении лат. Chrīstus, греч. Χρῑστός

Однако в соседнем вопросе пользователь @behemothus утверждает, что

> "Крест" может быть связан с Христом, но не образован из него. Т. е. крест и Христос восходят к одной и той же и.-е. основе, но появились в языке независимо друг от друга.

Вопрос. Возможно ли, чтобы слова *крест* и *Христос* восходили к одной и той же и.-е. основе и при этом появились независимо друг от друга? Какие доводы делают версию "независимости" более убедительной? Какие есть подобные случаи, имеющие отношение к русскому языку? Замечу, что слово *Христос* образовано от глагола *χρίω* ("мазать", "натирать") и никакого знаменательного отношения к фигуре креста не имело.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это вопрос отношения к личному мнению участника. Ничего содержательного. А по сути все давно отвечено. http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/422218.

Comment: behemoth, да пускай висит, хотя смысла приплетать сюда ваше мнение по другому вопросу, и правда, нет никакого.

Comment: IrinaGL, тут хуже, чем просто мое мнение. Автор выдает какой-то отрывок за коллективное мнение четырех разных авторов (не знаю, чье оно на самом деле, по стилю может быть Фасмер), да еще, как выяснилось, безбожно его перевирает.  По Пересвету получается, что из этого кусочка следует, что крест ***произошло*** от Христос. А не ***означало***, как там на самом деле. Это или вопиющая небрежность, или просто банальная нечистоплотность.

Answer (score 1):

На всякий случай отвечу.

> Возможно ли, чтобы слова крест и Христос восходили к одной и той же и.-е. основе и при этом появились независимо друг от друга?

При всей противоестественности постановки вопроса (напоминает "Возможно ли, что человек произошел от обезьяны, если он сотворен по промыслу божьему?") отвечу на пальцах.

Могут.

Ваш брат (гипотетический) "образован" от одного с Вами **отца**. Но не от Вас. Вы родственники, а не потомки друг друга.

"Христос" и "крест" могут (гипотетически) восходить к одному и.-е. "отцу", но не быть прямыми потомками.

А вообще постановка абсурдна и к лингвистике/языку не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: Словари указывают, что слово "крест" восходит к слову "Христос". Цитату из Крылова я приводил. Кто-то удаляет мои комментарии.

Comment: У Крылова нет слова слова "восходит" и смысл там другой. Под своим вопросом пишите что хотите. А под моим ответом соблюдайте хотя элементарную этику.   Мне просто надоело, что Вы опять все передергиваете.

Comment: У Крылова написано так: "Это слово стало результатом переосмысления имени собственного – "Христос". Есть контраргументы? Хоть один?

Comment: У Вас - нету. *"Это слово стало результатом переосмысления имени собственного – "Христос"* -  а слова "восходит" у Крылова нет. И хватит об этом.

Comment: Слово "восходит" значит "имеет что-н. своим началом, источником" (цитата из толкового словаря Ожегова). Если слово "крест" — "результат переосмысления имени собственного "Христос", то слово "Христос" его начало, значит "крест" к нему восходит. То есть у меня аргументы есть, а у Вас — нету. Прочитайте, кстати, Логику у Аристотеля. Поможет.

Comment: А слово "переосмыслено" не означает "иметь началом". Вот и все ваши "аргументы". Хорош троллить. А насчет аргументов - можете жаловаться в "Спортлото". Мне аргументы не нужны, я с Вами не спорю.

Comment: Раз слово есть результат переосмысления другого, значит оно имело в нём начало. Ваше неуклюжее жонглирование словами ничего не изменит. Я привёл четыре источника, а Вы ни одного контаргумента. В будущем потрудитесь не прибегать к народной этимологии.